# C# 2 Comboboxes with identical, not twice-selectable content

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a dialog form where the user has to selected which colums from a textfile he wants to use for drawing a graph.

If someone doesn't quite understand what I mean, please look at the following example:

- The dialog opens
- The user selects e.g. that the x-values of his graph shall be from the second column of the textfile
- The user selects e.g. that the y-values of his graph shall be from the third column of the textfile
- The user clicks "OK"

The problem I have is the following:

I want to prevent the user from selecting **the same column** for x and y values, which would result in a line in an angle of probably 45 degrees and make the graph useless.

Both comboboxes are filled with the same array of strings, which contains the headlines of the columns in the textfile. Getting those strings into the comboboxes works great, **but:**

I tried removing the item selected in one combobox from the other combobox and otherwise.
Before that, the currently selected item is stored in a variable and the items are reset to the default state, which means **all headlines from the textfile**.

But, as I programmatically set the index to where it was before, so that the user doesn't have to, the *SelectedIndexChanged* event fires and traps my code in an infinite loop.

```
public void setComboboxText()
{
    cbX.Items.Clear();
    cbY.Items.Clear();
    cbX.Items.AddRange(cbText);
    cbY.Items.AddRange(cbText);
}

void CbXSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = cbX.SelectedItem;
    setComboboxText();
    cbX.SelectedItem = item;
    cbY.Items.Remove(cbX.SelectedItem);
}

void CbYSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = cbY.SelectedItem;
    setComboboxText();
    cbY.SelectedItem = item;
    cbX.Items.Remove(cbY.SelectedItem);
}
```

The code does the following:

- The currently selected item is temporarily stored
- The items of the combobox are reset
- The currently selected item is set to be the item stores before
- The item selected in the changed box disappears from the other combobox

Any help appreciated, especially if someone could tell me if I can do what I want with another *event* or even without events.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> source1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> source2 = new List<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            source1.Add("item" + i);
            source2.Add("item" + i);
        }

        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(source1.ToArray());
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(source2.ToArray());
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.Items.Contains(comboBox1.SelectedItem))
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            List<string> updatedList = new List<string>();
            updatedList = (from x in source2
                           where !x.Equals(comboBox1.SelectedItem)
                           select x).ToList<string>();
            comboBox2.Items.AddRange(updatedList.ToArray());
        }

    }


    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Items.Contains(comboBox2.SelectedItem))
        {

            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            List<string> updatedList = new List<string>();
            updatedList = (from x in source1
                           where !x.Equals(comboBox2.SelectedItem)
                           select x).ToList<string>();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(updatedList.ToArray());
        }
    }


}
```

- Make the source collections available avaiable to each combobox SelectedIndexChanged handlers
- On each selection change update the source of the other combobox only if the newly selected item exists in the other combobox Items.

Comment: It took a while to convert the names, but I tried it and it works great, thanks!